# Bockstein morphism of spectral sequences

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, ring-spectra

Given an omega spectrum $E$, there is a type of chern character map given by its rationalization
$$r:E\to E\wedge M\mathbb{R}\;,$$
where $M\mathbb{R}$ denotes a Moore spectrum. The cofiber of the map
$$\mathbb{S}\to M\mathbb{R}$$
can be identified with an $M\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and smashing sequence on the left by $E$ yields a Bockstein sequence 
$$E\overset{r}{\to} E\wedge M\mathbb{R} \to E \wedge M\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\overset{\beta}{\to}\Sigma E\;.$$

Both $r$ and $\beta$ induce morphisms of corresponding Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequences. Although $\beta$ is usually trivial in practice (its $0$ when the coefficients are concentrated in even degrees for example). If I assume that $\pi_*(E)$ is concentrated in even degrees and is (say free) in those degrees, then there is also a Bockstien morphism corresponding to the sequence
$$0\to \pi_*(E)\to \pi_*(E)\otimes \mathbb{R} \to \pi_*(E)\otimes \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to 0,$$
induces a map on the $E_2$ page of the corresponding theories. I was hoping to show that this map commutes with the differentials and that the induced map on higher pages commutes (essentially that it defines a morphism of spectral sequences). Does anyone know if this is true, or know of a reference where this is discussed?

Comment: I'm confused. All morphisms of spectra induce a morphism of the corresponding AHSS, since you have a morphism of exact couples. Exactly where are you having problems?

Comment: @DenisNardin I just realized I wasn't very clear. I edited my post

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being overly dense, but I don't understand. Are you looking for a map $H_*(X;(E\wedge M\mathbb{Z})_*)\to H_*(X;\Sigma E_*)$ that commutes with the differentials? If so I believe my argument (there's a map of exact couples) should provide that

Comment: @DenisNardin Yes, $\beta$ induces a morphism of exact couples, but this is not the map I'm looking at. For example, take $K$ theory. Then $H^p(X;\pi_{-2q}(K\wedge M\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}))\simeq H^p(X;\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$. $H^p(X;\pi_{-2q}(\Sigma K))\simeq H^p(X;0)\simeq 0$. So the map induced by $\beta$ is just $0$. What I really want is to look at is the Bockstien $\tilde{\beta}:H^p(X;\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\to H^{p+1}(X;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Then $\beta$ is not the Bockstein you're looking for. In fact it is still not clear what is the map you're looking for, even at the $E_2$-page level. Could you clarify what are the source and target of the map?

Comment: @DenisNardin I've fixed my original post. Is it clear now? Im looking at the map induced by the Bockstien on *coefficients*. It goes from the $E_2$ page of the AHSS for $E\wedge M\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to the $E_2$ page for $\Sigma E$.

Comment: Ok, now I see: the morphism you are studying is the boundary homomorphism that arises when $\beta$ is 0 in homology. I'm sorry for being pedantic, I was missing the key context that $H_*\beta$ is 0. It is probably related to theorem 1.7 in this paper http://www.math.jhu.edu/~wsw/papers2/math/10-boundary-J3M2WZ1-1975.pdf (they study a similar map for the Adams-Novikov spectral sequence but I believe the situations are very similar)

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks! I'll take a look.